# How to apply sculpting to mirrored object

Tags: mirror

I made arm and mirrored it, applied the modifier. Then I started sculpting but symmetry was disabled. How can I apply those sculpting work to the other arm as well. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: you have a symmetry option in Sculpt mode (on the top right: X, Y and Z). Also, you can still symmetrize in Edit mode with Mesh > Symmetrize

Comment: That with edit mode is working, but when I do that, it symmetrize this detaily sculpted (on your right when you see picture) hand to unsculpted(on left). How can I reverse it?

Comment: when you symmetrize, you'll have access to the settings in the Operator box (bottom left, this box gives you the settings of the last operation), it will let you choose the symmetry axis

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode go into the header menu > *Mesh > Symmetrize*, then choose the symmetry axis in the *Operator* box:

[image]

It's also doable in *Sculpt* mode in the *Symmetry* panel:

[image]