# Mirror modifier does not work when I'm sculpting a mirrored object

Tags: sculpting, mirror

I'm having a sculpt mirroring issue, which was earlier discussed and solved in the forum, here ([How to apply sculpting to mirrored object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210163/how-to-apply-sculpting-to-mirrored-object/)). However the solution which was suggested there, does not help in my case. Perhaps some of you have met similar issues and may know the solution for it?

[image]

So what is happening, I’m having a beginner sculpting lesson, where I blocked out the basic shape. The workflow was like I created an object for the left shoulder for example, then mirrored it on the X axis, so the right shoulder was created. I applied this mirror modifier, then put on subdivision surface modifier on the objects, to add some faces for sculpting. Subdivision surface modifer was applied as well. Now I started sculpting, but when I use the brush on a source object, it doesn't apply the effects on the mirrored objects, those remain unchanged.

In the previous post, it was suggested to use the "Symmetrize" option in the menu, and set the symmetry axis on -X >> X. I have done these steps, but to me they did not work at all.
I'm using version 2.92 and the mirror effect on the body blocks, I use in this scene, work properly other than that (when moving objects in Object mode, etc.).

Has anyone met similar issues perhaps? Thank you in advance, if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've done a *Mesh > Symmetrize* in *Edit* mode to make sure that your model is perfectly symmetrical (you need to make sure that the origin of the object is at the center of the wanted symmetry, if it's not the case you need to move it), switch to *Sculpt* mode and enable the mirror option on the top right of the window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you MoonBoots for the reply.. The mirrored objects were created by mirorring the source on a third object, which is symmetrical (its origin is in X=0; Y=0). As I looked up the topic it should result the same effect as if the source objects' origin would be in zero point in the 3D World. I will check it if it may help..    Mirror option is enabled in Sculpt mode, however it hasn't changed the mirror effect. Thank you again!